# ActiveMQ Artemis two cluster in same network

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to setup two clusters for Dev and QA (or prod and staging) in same network. Each cluster consists of several nodes. Nodes will be reachable on network and I want to eliminate QA node clustering with Dev node. For this what should I changed, following is my config.

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="my-con">tcp://ip:61617</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="my-acc">tcp://ip:61617</acceptor>
</acceptors>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="bg-stage">
      <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
      <group-port>9877</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>100</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>my-con</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="dg-stage">
      <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
      <group-port>9877</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>my-con</connector-ref>
      <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-stage"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

Do I need to change different cluster-connection name, broadcast group and discovery groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `group-port` on the `broadcast-group` and `discovery-group` from the default `9876` to `9877` should be sufficient to isolate the clusters from each other. Changing the names in the configuration won't really impact anything other than your own ability to differentiate the configuration between the environments.